# Update multiple rows at once in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a vector of values

vector = [ 10, 11, 10, 11, 12 ];

and an initialized database table

[image]

My goal is to update the value of each row ( which is initialized to -1 ) with a value from the vector. So the id =1, will have value 10, the id = 2, value 11 etc.

I can do this in a loop, ie for every value in vector update the corresponding row.

However I was wondering if I can do this with one update statement. I am using MySQL.

The final state after the update should be:

[image]

The Nth row (sorted) in the database should have the Nth value of the vector.

Comment: Is the id a primary key in your table? and What would the value of id in the 3rd record be?

Comment: Yes id is the primary key. The value of the the Nth record would be the (Nth-1) value in the vector (assuming the vector index starts from 0)

Comment: I see duplicate entries in the vector, and since the id is a primary key the update cannot be done.

Comment: Please show the expected end result donc use "etc" to describe it, as in your case there could be many solutions.

Comment: @Nerevar I added a print screen, to show the final state.

Comment: Ok thanks that is what I thought in the first place but the first answer that was given to your question confused me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following (as far as I know it is impossible to do this with an update statement):

```
INSERT INTO table (id,value) VALUES (1,10),(2,11),(3,10),(4,11),(5,12)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES(value)
```

What does it do is an insert statement that checks if key already exists, if so it will update the row.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you transform your vector into a table :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Vectors(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Value int not null)

INSERT INTO Vectors VALUES(10),(11),(10) ...

UPDATE MyTable AS T 
INNER JOIN Vectors AS V ON V.ID=T.ID 
SET T.Value = V.Value 
WHERE T.Value = -1

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE Vectors
```

Answer (score 2):

**TRY THIS:** I think we can achieve this through `UNION ALL` in a single query

```
UPDATE test t
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 1 id, 10 val UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 id, 11 val UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 id, 10 val UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 id, 11 val UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 id, 12 val) vector ON vector.id = t.id
SET t.val = vector.val           
WHERE t.val = -1;
```